# how to simulate a touch event in android using java code

Tags: android, touch-event

I am trying to write a code for simulating a touch event at location (x,y).

Requirements:

I don't want to use monkey runner tool, i want to code at Java level only.

i/p is location (x,y) and 
o/p should be a touch event at (x,y)

I searched through many articles in stackoverflow & google, did not find a good one

your Help appreciated Thanks in advance,

Thanks 
Murthy

Comment: Do you need to provide touch to specific view or specific activity?

Comment: i wanted to try for any view, through a single activity. since i wanted to use for any application (application can be in many views).

Comment: "i wanted to use for any application" - It is not possible on a stock build of the OS. You can only send touch events to your own Activities.